# How to pass directive scope value to a global javascript function called in template of the same directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I've a question regarding the way values work in **directives**. I have one directive which has a template and in the same template I want to call a (globally defined) javascript function and into that javascript function I want to pass the value that I get from my **directive** (It might sound a bit confusing).
Here is the example code.

```
angular.module("Shell").directive("myFormField", function () {
return {
    scope: {
        text: "@",
        required: "@",
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template:
        '<div>' +
        '<label style="white-space: nowrap;font-weight: normal;width: 100% !important">'+globalLoadText(text)+
        '<div style="margin-top: 1.5px;" ng-transclude />' +
        '</label>' +
        '</div>'
};
});
```

globalLoadText() is my global method defined out side angular(in a normal js file thats in the root scope) **text** would be the value that I want get from the directive.

I hope I have written down my question clearly. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Before we give you the power to do something that  sounds really smelly, can you explain why you have to use a global function ?

Comment: Why try to get outside of the AngularJS eco-system? If you have a global function, create a Service to share the function between directives, controllers, etc. That way it's modular and stays within AngularJS' digest cycle.

Comment: I think the problem is, your function will evaluate first, while `text` doesn't exist in the scope. Would it work to use a filter instead of a function? So you can do `{{text | globalLoadText}}`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 1):

I strongly urge you to explain why you need a global function because its not hard to accomplish what you want.  But that doesn't mean you should.

```
angular
  .module("Shell")
  .directive("myFormField", myFormFieldDirective);


myFormFieldController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function myFormFieldController($scope) {
  $scope.globalLoadText = _globalLoadText;

  function _globalLoadText() {
    return globalLoadText($scope.text);
  }
}


function myFormFieldDirective() {
  return {
    scope: {
      text: "@",
      required: "@",
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    controller: myFormFieldController,
    template: '<div>' +
      '<label style="white-space: nowrap;font-weight: normal;width: 100% !important">{{globalLoadText()}}' +
      '<div style="margin-top: 1.5px;" ng-transclude />' +
      '</label>' +
      '</div>'
  };
}
```